# Anatomizing lua code with lua itself

Tags: lua

I have a config file written in lua with ***kind of*** a given structure, that **later** should dynamically create a GUI:

```lua
-- Input config file
package.path = '?.fsl;'
require "init"

global_unit(mm)                    --   Global unit (m, cm, mm)
pickdist(0.001)                    --   Snap distance
cosys(polar)                       --   Set system of coordinates

-- Define model name, for filenames etc.
new_model_force(model_name,"from main.fsl")

-- Define FE Control Data
m.hc_min          =         95.000 --   Limit demagnetisa > 0:[%]Hc;<0:[kA/m]
m.con_hdcopy      =          1.000 --   Hc-copy:Name:auto:0;intact:1; none:-1
m.b_max           =          2.200 --   Max Induction [T] in colorgradation
m.b_min           =          0.000 --   Move inside: 0 ; Move outside: > 0

pre_models("FE-contr-data");

pre_models("connect_models");

-- Define the Basic Model Parameter
m.tot_num_slot    =             QS --   Number of slots               (>= 1)
m.num_poles       =          2 * p --   Number of poles 2p            (>= 2)
m.npols_gen       =         2*p*mf --   Number of poles simulated     (>= 1) --=m.num_poles * m.num_sl_gen / m.tot_num_slot
m.num_slots       =          QS*mf --   Number of slots in model
m.arm_length      =            lFe --   Effect. armature length          [mm]
m.fc_radius       =   (Di-delta)/2 --   Radius air-gap center            [mm] --=(m.inside_diam-ag)/2

pre_models("basic_modpar");

...
```

All m.whatever variables belong to the respective pre_models(...) statement below.
The number and names of the variables for each "pre_models(...) - block" are not known sometimes, same applies for the "pre_models(...) - blocks" itself.

GUI should show sth. like:

```
Tab1 = General settings: global_unit -> mm, pickdist -> 0.001, etc.
Tab2 = FE-contr-data: m.hc_min -> 95.000, m.con_hdcopy -> 1.000, etc.
Tab3 = connect_models:
Tab4 = basic_modpar: m.tot_num_slot -> 36, m.num_poles -> 30, etc.
```

..where QS = 36 and p = 15 is defined in the file init.

Wish: Code don't have to know the terms "FE-contr-data", global_unit(...) etc.

Any idea how to approach?

Comment: Intercept (using metatable(_G)) access to `pre_models()` and run this script. Print serialized `m` on every invocation of intercepted `pre_models()`.

Comment: Dear whoever, here was one answer visible that was maybe helpful, now I can not see it anymore, the guys name was sth. similar to "Skriptunov". Would be nice to get this answer back.

Comment: [This question is being discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370541/deleted-comment)

Comment: Chances are the answer was deleted by the author due to the above mentioned discussion.

Answer (score 0):

> I am only answering b/c this answer has no answer so it can be classified as answered.

You need to intercept (using `metatable(_G)`) access to `pre_models()` and run the script. Finally, print a serialized `m` on every invocation of the intercepted version of `pre_models()`.